# How do I find the cartesian equation for a circle which is centered around the origin and intersects with the closest single point of a truncus?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, circles

The title is poorly worded. Essentially, there is a generic truncus on a cartesian plane, that is  $\frac{1}{x^{2}}$.

The question is, how would I find a cartesian equation in order to represent a circle that intersects with the closest possible point on the truncus to the origin. In other words, it has to *barely* touch the closest edge.

From my limited knowledge of cartesian equations, I know I can use the formula $x^{2}+y^{2}=r^{2}$ in order to get a circle that is on the origin and adjust the value of $r^{2}$ to change the radius of said circle.

How mathematically would I get the $r^{2}$ value (or really whatever that value has to be)? I know the solution is roughly 1.37 but I'd imagine that it's an irrational number.

To help, I've got an image of what I'm looking for:
[Desmos showing solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LE5iQ.png)

Comment: you might like to know that $r^2=2^{\frac13}+2^{-\frac23}$

Answer (score 1):

Well, I got to an answer. I'd say it's not very elegant but it hardly matters. It's just math that happens to work. Variable d is equal to the radius, but by habit I use d for distance.

I found the $d^{2}$ value to be $x^{2}+\frac{1}{x^{4}}$, then taking the derivative of this I ended up with $d^{2}$ prime $= 2x - \frac{4}{x^{5}}$, giving me the x values of $\pm2^{\frac{1}{6}}$. From there it's basic substitution to get $y=\frac{2^{\frac{2}{3}}}{2}$ (which applies to points on both the positive and negative x quadrants).

Then, I took $d=\sqrt{\left(2^{\frac{1}{6}}\right)^{2}+\left(\frac{2^{\frac{2}{3}}}{2}\right)^{2}}$ to give me the distance using pythag, giving me $d=\frac{\sqrt{3}\cdot2^{\frac{2}{3}}}{2}$.

Finally, the cartesian equation for the circle is $x^{2}+y^{2}=\frac{3}{2}\sqrt[3]{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint...

Find the equation of the normal to the curve $y=\frac{1}{x^2}$ at the point $(t,\frac{1}{t^2})$. Find the value of $t$ for which this normal passes through the origin.

Can you take it from here?